# Production iOS Push Certificates Issues

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, ssl-certificate

My push notifications are working in development but not in production. When I create a Production SSL certificate and open it in the keychain, there is no private key associated with it. Therefore, I am not able to export into a .p12 file and use on my server. How do I fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same private key as the one you used in development. Just make sure that you send the push notification to the production server gateway.push.apple.com NOT gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.